# VarcharType mismatch Spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, varchar

I'am trying to change the schema of a dataframe. every time i have a column of string type i want to change it's type to VarcharType(max) where max is the maximum lentgh of string in that column. i wrote the following code. ( i want to export the dataframe later to sql server and i don't want to have nvarchar in sql server so i'am trying to limit it on spark side )

```
val df = spark.sql(s"SELECT * FROM $tableName")

var l : List [StructField] = List()

val schema = df.schema
schema.fields.foreach(x => {

  if (x.dataType == StringType) {
    val dataColName = x.name
    val maxLength = df.select(dataColName).reduce((x, y) => {
      if (x.getString(0).length >= y.getString(0).length) {
        x
      } else {
        y
      }
    }).getString(0).length

    val dataType = VarcharType(maxLength)
    l = l :+ StructField(dataColName, dataType)
  } else {
    l = l :+ x
  }
})

val newSchema = StructType(l)
val newDf = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, newSchema)
```

However when running it i get this error.

```
  20/01/22 15:29:44 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: scala.MatchError: 
  VarcharType(9) (of class org.apache.spark.sql.types.VarcharType)
  scala.MatchError: VarcharType(9) (of class org.apache.spark.sql.types.VarcharType)
```

Can a dataframe column can be of type VarcharType(n) ?

Comment: Can you use StringType which will map to a varchar column on sqlserver

Comment: Problem is i want to limit the string length. Can i do that with StringType ?

Comment: StringType maps to NVARCHAR(MAX). I think you can modify it. I will answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data mapping from a database to/from dataframe happens in the dialect class. For MS SQL server the class is `org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.MsSqlServerDialect`. You can inherit from this and override `getJDBCType` to influence datatype mapping from a dataframe to a table. Then register your dialect for it to take effect.

I have done this for Oracle (not sqlserver), however it can be done similarly.

```
//Change this
  override def getJDBCType(dt: DataType): Option[JdbcType] = dt match {
    case TimestampType => Some(JdbcType("DATETIME", java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP))
    case StringType => Some(JdbcType("NVARCHAR(MAX)", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR))
    case BooleanType => Some(JdbcType("BIT", java.sql.Types.BIT))
    case _ => None
  }
```

You can't use VarcharType because it is not a `DataType`. Also you can't check length of actual data because it is not exposed. You only have access to "dt: DataType", so you can set a default size for NVARCHAR if max is not acceptable.